# Oracle, identify that a row is the last in the group

Tags: sql, database, oracle

In the table below I would like to delete or update the second row (2,3,100,test2) if and only if is the last row of the session (100).

For example the third line can be modified because it is the last line grouped by session_id=100, but the first and second lines should not be deleted/updated.

How can I efficiency do this?

The ID column as you can see in the schema below is an autogenerated number that always increases.

[image]

You can find my schema below:

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST_T" 
   (    
   "ID" NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE , 
    "PARENT" NUMBER, 
    "SESSION_ID" NUMBER, 
    "DATA" VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE)
   ) 

Insert into TEST_T (ID,PARENT,SESSION_ID,DATA) values (1,1,100,'test');
Insert into TEST_T (ID,PARENT,SESSION_ID,DATA) values (3,2,100,'test2');
Insert into TEST_T (ID,PARENT,SESSION_ID,DATA) values (4,33,100,'test3');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the row using:

```
delete from test_t t
    where t.session_id = 100 and
          t.id = (select max(t2.id) from test_t t2 where t2.session_id = t.session_id);
```

Similar logic can be used for an `update`.

Comment: This code works, but I would like somehow to pass the parent (eg parent=2) and get an error if it is not the last. The last parent is 33.

Comment: @cateof . . . I don't see what `parent` has to do with your question.  If you have a new question, ask it as a new question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Does the parent with largest value is the last parent? If so, you can try to use the code below

```
DELETE FROM test_t b
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM (SELECT A.*, MAX(parent) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY parent) OVER (PARTITION BY session_id) last_parent
                         FROM TEST_T A) a 
                WHERE a.last_parent = b.parent
                  and a.session_id = b.session_id)
```

or, you can use the LAST_VALUE function, sample query below

```
SELECT A.*, last_value(parent) OVER (order by session_id) last_value
  FROM TEST_T A
 ORDER BY SESSION_ID, PARENT DESC
```